# Try-Except on performing an expansion

Tags: expansion, protected-macro

Is it possible to write a function that essentially does:

```
function \tryexpand (\foo):
    try:
         expand(\foo)
    except (Argument of \@following has an extra }):
         store "\relax" in `\result`
    else:
         store expansion of `\foo` in `\result`
    
    return \result
```

Context: I am trying to do `\edef\result{\expandafter\empty\foo}` (circumventing `\protect`), which works if `\foo` doesn't need any arguments, but fails otherwise.

#### Test-Cases

```tex
\newcommand{\needsthree}[3]{#3#2#1}
\protected\def\foo{\needsthree}
% --> \tryexpand{\foo} should lead to \result being macro:->\relax
\newcommand{\needsnone}{42}
\protected\def\bar{\needsnone}
% --> \tryexpand{\bar} should lead to \result being macro:->42
```

Comment: TeX has no try-except, so no, this isn't possible. But instead of asking for forgiveness you can ask for allowance. You can parse the output of `\meaning` to see if the macro takes arguments.

Comment: What do you expect to get from expanding a macro requiring arguments without supplying them?

Comment: @egreg an error to occur, hence the question about try-expect.

Comment: @Skillmon seems difficult. One could easily test if the string contains a `#`, but for example if `\foo` is something like `macro:->\UTFviii@three@octets`, then it doesn't work.

Comment: @Hyperplane it's the only chance you got except for not doing it at all. As I said, TeX has no try-except. If LuaTeX is an option maybe there's something in it that you can wrap in `pcall(...)`, but I'm not sure how to trigger one step of expansion from within the Lua layer and if Lua would catch an exception at all from erroring TeX code. Thinking about it, I wouldn't bet on it.